# Regarding a sum of a partition of unity

Tags: general-topology

Cover a manifold $M$ with open sets with compact closures, take a locally finite refinement of this cover and $\{\varphi_i\}$ a partition of unity subordinate to this cover. Why is the map $$h(x) = \sum_i i\varphi_i(x)$$ proper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define an unbounded sequence in a manifold to be a sequence $(x_n)$ such that there is no compact set $K$ that contains all $x_i$. Given a map $f: M \to N$ between manifolds, it's equivalent to proper that all unbounded sequences map to unbounded sequences. (Morally, a proper map is just one that "goes to infinity as you go to infinity".)

So pick an unbounded sequence $(x_n)$. For convenience, pick an exhaustion by compact sets $K_0 \subset K_1 \subset \dots = M$, and pass to a subsequence such that $x_i \not\in K_{i-1}$. By the definition of unboundedness, for each $i$, there is some $x_{n_i}$ such that $\varphi_j(x_{n_i}) = 0$ for all $j < i$. In particular, $\sum_j j\varphi_j(x_{n_i}) = \sum_{j=i}^\infty j\varphi_j(x_{n_i}) \geq i$, because $\sum_j \varphi_j(x) = 1$ for any $x$.

Thus we have demonstrated an unbounded subsequence of $f(x_j)$, and hence shown that $f(x_j)$ itself is unbounded, as desired.

Comment: Thanks! As for proving the equivalent definition assuming unbounded goes to unbounded: I picked a large compact $K \subset N$, assumed its preimage was not compact and took an unbounded sequence completely contained in it and applied $f$, yielding a contradiction. Does that seem right?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yup, that's it.